# How to make sure conversation between user and the chatbot remain within an app - Dialogflow

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es, flutter-dependencies

The question that I need answer to: How can you store the chat between users and the chatbot within the app? Right now, I've managed to integrate Dialogflow with an application but once I exited the chat page the conversation will be lost...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a local database service or an online database service like Firebase.

Some local data storage packages:

1. [SQFLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)
2. [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)
3. [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: I am still currently -so- new to flutter so if you could help further by giving me video or code resources on how to actually do it, that would be amazing! All I’ve seen is the query type database, but i just need the conversation to not be lost and allow the user to refer to the Messages just by opening the chat interface

Comment: You can just search the internet for it. I would recommend using `Hive`. It is simple and effective.

Comment: Do you know which one? Because on YouTube there’s so little video of it

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/flutter-community/storing-local-data-with-hive-and-provider-in-flutter-a49b6bdea75a) Medium article looks good.